# How to print the param value inside node attribute using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm passing a param value into XSLT. Later I want to print the param value inside my node attribute. Can anyone please help me on this?

Below is the XSLT code I'm trying to use-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Course_Registration_Records_-_GETA"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="StuName"/>
        
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Student wd:Descriptor="$StuName1">
            </wd:Student>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encase the variable reference in curly braces.

```
<wd:Student wd:Descriptor="{$StuName1}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute value template `<wd:Student wd:Descriptor="{$StuName1}">...</wd:Student>`.